# Интеграция онлайн кнопки в тг канал aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Когда пытаюсь к сообщению, которое бот отправляет в телеграм канал, добавить инлайн кнопку, то бот не отправляет сообщение в канал, но если убрать кнопку то сообщение отправляется

Вот мой код:

```
greet_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
greet_kb.add(button_hi5)
await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, text, reply_markup=greet_kb)
```

Comment: Покажите какая возникает ошибка

Comment: он просто не отправляет сообщение, даже ошибки не выдает никакой

Comment: Меня смущает эта строка greet_kb.add(button_hi5), по-моему, так добавляются кнопки в билдере. Попробуй так greet_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button_hi5) а add убери

Comment: попробовал так, но теперь он отправил сообщение, но инлайн кнопка не появилась

Comment: button_hi5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="ПОДПИСКА")
 greet_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button_hi5)
 await bot.send_message(channel_id, text, reply_markup=greet_kb)